# Multi selection will be lost when I clicked another column item in CListCtrl

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

1. Please see the screen shot (which is a sample)
2. I have a list view with 2 columns, the first one is "name" and the second one is "status"
3. when I clicks the light bulb in second column, it will be changed between status 'on' and 'off'
4. currently, I need to implement a multi select function. It is to use ctrl or shift to select several rows, and then click any one 'bulb' of them, and to switch the status of all selected items.

The problem is:

When I clicked the 'light bulb' the multi selected will be lost. It means when I uses API GetSelectedCount, it will return 0.

My Investigation:

When I clicked the 'light bulb', the event about item change will be triggered. and the OnItemChanged event will be triggered before OnClick event (that's why API GetSelectedCount will return 0 in event OnClock). 
I wanted to cache the multi selected items in event OnItemChanged, but I failed because every item will trigger OnItemChanged event once.

for exmple: if I multi selected 3 items in the list view, and then click the 'light bulb' of the 3rd item, the event OnItemChanged will be triggered for 3 times, to notify the 3 items were un-selected. So, in OnClick event of (click light bulb), I don't know which items were selected in previous operations.

Furthermore, I still want to keep the multi selectionw after I click the 'light bulb'.

Any help will be much appreciated?

ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(LVN_ITEMCHANGED, OnItemChanged)

ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT_EX(NM_CLICK, OnClick)

void CListCtrl::OnItemChanged( NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult )  {......}

BOOL CListCtrl::OnClick(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) {......}

[image: screen shot sample]

Comment: This is the standard behavior of the list control. If you want to do multi-selection and set all the selected items to a new state, all at once, the usual way is to implement a right-click context-menu. In the menu you can have a menu item like "Enable selected items". And when the user click this menu item you can then iterate through all items in the list so as to modify the state of the selected item to the desired state.

Comment: I found a solution to implement this. Just intercept the message in "PreTranslateMessage". set some flag such as bLight = ture; then in the event of clistctrl itemchanging, if the bLight = true, set the *result = 1;

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I solved this by intercepting the OnLButtonDown message.

First add the ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN() to your message map declaration.
Add the function prototype afx_msg void OnLButtonDown(UINT, CPoint); to your list control class.

My function looked a bit like this:

```
   afx_msg void OnLButtonDown(UINT, CPoint)
    {       
        //We need to intercept the left button down
        //message so that we don't lose our multi-select
        //if the user has clicked on an icon
        DWORD pos = GetMessagePos();
        CPoint pt(short(LOWORD(pos)), short(HIWORD(pos)));
        ScreenToClient(&pt);

        uint flags;           
        int itemIndex = HitTest(pt, &flags);

        //We didn't hit a list item or an icon
        if (itemIndex == -1 || !(LVHT_ONITEMICON & flags))
        {
           ::CListCtrl::OnLButtonDown(var, point);
           return;
        }
        else
        {
            uint selectedItemCount = GetSelectedCount();
            int nItem = -1;
            if (selectedItemCount > 0)
            {      

                for (nItem = GetNextItem(-1, LVNI_SELECTED); nItem >= 0; 
                nItem = GetNextItem(nItem, LVNI_SELECTED))
                {    
                    //Do whatever you need to do to selected items
                }
            }
        }
    }
```